# developing custom ios/ipad application for accessing windows shared folders in Active Directory

Tags: ios, ipad, active-directory, cifs, shared-directory

This is a broad question so I don't expect any explicit/exact answer. I only want ideas.

I need to develop a custom iPad application to access documents (upload/download) from a windows shared folder in an Active Directory, preserving the user permission/access. These has been my thoughts:

- First, I have look into the open source project seafile. It's basically a repository that synchronizes with a windows folder, but it manages the user-permissions in his own way.
- Secondly I though of implementing the cifs protocol on my application. But I have read it´s a troublesome protocol to implement.
- Third I think on running an application on the server with access to the active directory and implementing the connection between the iPad and the server application, so I get rid of the cifs protocol.

I don't know how to handle this problem as it seems a HUGE task for only one person in a 1-2 month schedule. There is some open-source tool/app/project I can use? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Active Directory does not store any documents. It stores entities/objects.

Comment: Sorry if I have not been clear enough. I want to say: access documents of a shared folder in an active directory.

Comment: A directory still does not offer any folders. You want to access a Windows share?! If so, change your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least one application for iPads that you could use to get access to your Windows share. 
FileExplorer,developed by Steven Chang. 
With the application installed in a iPad or iPhone you could access any windows share in a network, even trough iOS VPN.
I'm using it on daily basis where you would like to access files and even download these in local folder in the app itself.

Best regards: Jan